# grouby function with filtered conditions

Tags: python, arrays, pandas, group-by, split

```
f = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': ['name1','name2','name3']
                  'genre': [['comedy', 'action'];['comedy','scifi']; 
                            ['thriller','action']]
                  'distributor': ['disney', 'disney','parmount'})
```

#what if the genre has multiple values in it now name is both part of genre[0] and genre[1] if i use groupby

```
res = f[f['distributor'] == 'disney'].groupby(['genre'])
```

## desired output

only want movie launched by disney

```
distributor     genre     count of movies
   disney        action        1
   disney        comedy        2
   disney         scifi         1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Explode your list then count values:

```
out = df.loc[df['distributor'] == 'disney', 'genre'].explode().value_counts()
print(out)

# Output
comedy    2
action    1
scifi     1
Name: genre, dtype: int64
```

**Update**

```
out = (df.explode('genre').query("distributor == 'disney'")
        .value_counts(['distributor', 'genre'], sort=False)
        .rename('count').reset_index())
print(out)

# Output
  distributor   genre  count
0      disney  action      1
1      disney  comedy      2
2      disney   scifi      1
```

**Update 2**

It seems your `genre` column does not contain a list but a strings. Try to convert this column as a list with `ast.literal_eval` before using the code above:

```
import ast

df['genre'] = df['genre'].str.replace(';', ',').apply(ast.literal_eval)

# OR

df['genre'] = pd.eval(df['genre'].str.replace(';', ','))

# Execute now df.explode(...)...
```

Comment: count works fine the distributor works fine but genre isnt splitting heres the output i got   i will edit the output in the question

Comment: I updated my answer according your comment. Can you kindly check it please?

Comment: shows ast not defined any library to download for that? yeah its a string sorry forgot to mention

Comment: `ast` is a module of the standard library

Comment: So you really have semicolon in your string?

Comment: no i am extarcting data directly from a csv  file so i guess it treats that like a whole string

Comment: what do i do to get that ast thing working?

Comment: can u guide me to a link or anything where i can understand the structure sometimes i be usingh groupby and the other function we cannot use these in random sequence they have to in astructures sequence so where can i find the structures

Comment: Did you already read [`Split-Apply-Combine`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/user_guide/groupby.html)?

Comment: no i just m learning by attempting random question not following any path will try split_apply_combine thanks

Comment: Like that https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69701276/how-to-groupby-and-calculate-new-field-with-python-pandas or https://stackoverflow.com/q/70882721/15239951  and https://stackoverflow.com/q/69441593/15239951 for example?

Answer (score 0):

Easy and clear to do with [`datar`](https://github.com/pwwang/datar) that reimagines pandas' APIs:

```py
>>> import pandas as pd
>>> df = pd.DataFrame({'Movie': ['name1','name2','name3'],
...                   'genre': [['comedy', 'action'], ['comedy','scifi'],
...                             ['thriller','action']],
...                   'distributor': ['disney', 'disney','parmount']})
>>> df
   Movie               genre distributor
0  name1    [comedy, action]      disney
1  name2     [comedy, scifi]      disney
2  name3  [thriller, action]    paramount
>>>
>>> from datar.all import f, filter, unchop, count
[2022-03-31 11:47:44][datar][WARNING] Builtin name "filter" has been overriden by datar.
>>> (
...     df 
...     >> filter(f.distributor == "disney") 
...     >> unchop(f.genre) 
...     >> count(f.distributor, f.genre)
... )
  distributor    genre       n
     <object> <object> <int64>
0      disney   comedy       2
1      disney   action       1
2      disney    scifi       1
[TibbleGrouped: distributor (n=1)]
```

Comment: shows filter not registered error i pipo installed  datar still

Comment: `filter` not registered for which type?

Comment: filter' is not registered for type: <class 'datar.core.operator.DatarOperator'>.

Comment: Could submit an issue to the repo with the code you ran?